# ASYNC/AWAIT not working on RECURSIVE functions on nodeJS project

Tags: javascript, recursion, async-await, axios

I'm very exited to be working on a nodeJS REST API project that provides top sales data about the largest ecommerce giant in Latin America (MercadoLibre) by webscraping the heck out of it with Cheerio which is like jQuery for the backend

- [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ramiro-e/MasVendidosAPI-MercadoLibre-Tracker)
- [Project on VS Code Online](https://vscode.dev/github/ramiro-e/MasVendidosAPI-MercadoLibre-Tracker)

like many others they use a non specific number of nested categories to organize their products, and im trying to map the hole category tree automatically to get back every category's "most sold" list to then save it and provide it as an API.

My problem is that the recuring functions don't seem await fetching with Axios but let me explain how it works first so you can follow along

The first thing I did was build a sort of kickstart function, that would map the main category tree to then call the recursive functions to iterate over every (n)*sub-categories.... like the one down below

```
const categoriasURL = 'https://www.mercadolibre.com.ar/categorias#nav-header'

async function checkCategories() {
    try {
        let response = await axios(categoriasURL);
        let html = response.data
        let $ = cheerio.load(html)
        let categories = {}
        let subcategories = {}


        $('.categories__container', html).each( async function () {
            let categoryName =  lodash.kebabCase(lodash.deburr($(this).find('.categories__title a').text()))
            $(this).children().find('.categories__item').each(async function(){
                let subcategory = lodash.kebabCase(lodash.deburr($(this).find('a').text()))
                let subcatList
                try {
                    let subcategoryFetch = await axios($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
                    console.log('CAT   ' + $(this).find('a').attr('href'))
                    subcatList = await checkSubcategories (subcategoryFetch)
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log("error en checkCategories")
                }
            })
        })

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

after maping the main categories the function above calls `checkSubcategories (subcategoryFetch)` to check if there are more subcategories to be checked and if so it will call `fetchSubcat(url)` to fetch them and call `checkSubcategories (subcategoryFetch)` function again and so on and so forth

checkSubcategories (fetched):

```
async function checkSubcategories (fetched){
    let html = fetched.data
    let subcatList = {}
    $ = cheerio.load(html)
    if ($('.ui-search-filter-dl .ui-search-filter-dt-title:contains("Categorías")').length) {
        $('.ui-search-filter-dl .ui-search-filter-dt-title:contains("Categorías")').parent().children().find('.ui-search-filter-container').each( async function(){
            let subcategoryName = lodash.kebabCase(lodash.deburr($(this).find('.ui-search-filter-name').text()))

            try {
                let url = await $(this).find('a').attr('href')
                let fetchedData = await fetchSubcat(url)
                //
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("error en checkSubcategories")
            }
            
        })

    } else {
        return {moreSubcat: false, url:"url"}
    }
}
```

fetchSubcat(url):

```
async function fetchSubcat(url){
    try {
        let subcategoryFetch = await axios(url);
        let subcatList
        subcatList = await checkSubcategories (subcategoryFetch)
        return subcatList
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error en fetchSubcat')
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: I.E. [`cherio each`](https://cheerio.js.org/classes/Cheerio.html#each) only waits for its argument function to return - which `async` functions do synchronously by returning a promise.  Hence the `each` call on line 6 of `checkSubcategories` finishes all iterations without waiting for anything. The expected result is that the promise returned by `checkSubcategories` will be synchronously resolved with `undefined` by code execution falling out the bottom of `checkSubcategories`.